# Can a C variable be constrained to a certain read/write speed?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, embedded

I'm working with an embedded system (RISC-V based) where a processor is connected to a data bus, which again is connected to a UART module. When the data bus is read/written, it needs two processor cycles before it is ready for new read/write operations, otherwise it yields an error.

The data bus is memory mapped like so:

```
struct WishboneBus {
    volatile uint32_t read_addr;
    volatile uint32_t write_addr;
    volatile uint32_t write_data;
    volatile uint32_t read_data;
};

#define WISHBONE_BUS ((struct WishboneBus *) (0x4000000))
```

I would like to write code like this:

```
void wb_write(uint32_t addr, uint32_t data) {
    WISHBONE_BUS->write_data = data;
    WISHBONE_BUS->write_addr = addr;
}
```

When the program is compiled with -O0, it yields these six instructions:

```
    WISHBONE_BUS->write_data = data;
    153c:   400007b7            lui a5,0x40000
    1540:   fd842703            lw  a4,-40(s0)
    1544:   00e7a423            sw  a4,8(a5) # 40000008 <BUS_START+0x8>
    WISHBONE_BUS->write_addr = addr;
    1548:   400007b7            lui a5,0x40000
    154c:   fdc42703            lw  a4,-36(s0)
    1550:   00e7a223            sw  a4,4(a5) # 40000004 <BUS_START+0x4>
```

But with -Os, it yields these instructions:

```
    WISHBONE_BUS->write_data = data;
     df8:   40000737            lui a4,0x40000
     dfc:   00b72423            sw  a1,8(a4) # 40000008 <BUS_START+0x8>
    WISHBONE_BUS->write_addr = addr;
     e00:   00a72223            sw  a0,4(a4)
```

(The non-relevant parts of the function call are removed.)
In the -O0 case, there are two instructions (cycles) between each `sw`, so it works. But in the -Os case, there are two `sw` after each other, and the bus yields an error because the bus needs two cycles between read/write operations.

This motivates the question:
Can a C variable be constrained to a certain read/write speed?

I know it is possible to add `nop` instructions to make this work, but the number of required `nop` instructions will depend on the optimization. And I realize I can use macros to fix this, but I would like an elegant solution. E.g., some kind of `__attribute__((min_access_cycles(2)))` or something.

Comment: If you need this functionality, implement an accessor function in assembly and call it from your high-level code.

Comment: For access to hardware devices it's nothing unusual for such wait-states. This is something you have to design for, using for example assembly-coded accessor functions as mentioned by @fuz. Or adding short delays in your C code.

Comment: Re "*but the number of required nop instructions will depend on the optimization*", So do the rest of the function in assembly too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not have that feature, and also GCC probably doesn't know how RISC-V instructions get mapped to clock cycles on your particular system.  So you will have to use some amount of assembly to get the timing right.

I prefer using as little assembly when possible (e.g. just a few NOPs written in an inline assembly block), so the compiler is more free to optimize things.  Also, calling a separate function that can't be inlined is often less efficient because the compiler could be forced to save some registers to the stack, and it has to put the function arguments in particular registers to conform to the ABI.

Comment: Since you mention optimization, `asm volatile("nop" ::: );` (without a `memory` clobber) *is* still ordered wrt. `volatile` accesses (like to the OP's struct members), which you need to be using for all MMIO accesses anyway.  So that should work well and still let the compiler keep non-volatile things in registers across it.  (`asm("nop" :::)` is implicitly `volatile` because it has no output operands, so that's also correct. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile)